# How to convert double-backslash unicode chars to originals in Python?

Tags: python

I am working with multilingual strings and many of them have Hebrew, Arabic, Chinese etc. characters in them that are encoded and appear in this format: `\\x00`, i.e. a two-digit double-backslash escape. The strings are in bytes format, i.e. they appear in this format:  `b''`.

I have read several comments here on SO and other sites but still can't get my head around as to how to convert these back to original characters.

I know that if the backslashes were single ones, the following would solve it:

```
b'\xd7\x90\xd7\x91\xd7\x92'.decode('utf-8')
```

and it would return: `'אבג'`.

But when applying the same `.decode('utf-8')` method on my string, the outputs are messed up.

```
b'\\xd7\\x90\\xd7\\x91\\xd7\\x92'.decode('utf-8')
```

will return: `'×\x90×\x91×\x92'`.

I really wouldn't want to apply regex on it, there must be a nicer solution that I am not aware of!

Comment: A simple string replace for the `\\\` ... maybe?

Comment: What is producing that string? It's not doing it correctly.

Comment: @chepner I am unfortunately not very sure anymore, it was parsed from a site a long while ago and stored in a csv. This is the form I got it. Do you mean it should definitely not be encoded this way, as in this was supposedly an error when parsing?

Comment: Of course, I totally agree with you. However, I am no longer able to trace it back who and when did the parsing of the data and we are talking about several GBs of information altogether that would be very expensive to parse again, this is why my question arose. :)

Comment: If this is read from a CSV it should have been stored as the `\xd7` char, not as the literal `\xd7`. I'm guessing that is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but assuming your string has no quotation marks in it, you might try

```
>>> x = b'\\xd7\\x90\\xd7\\x91\\xd7\\x92'
>>> ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(f'"{x}"')).decode()
'אבג'
```

This is based the assumption that the original value was indeed a normally encoded `str` object:

```
>>> 'אבג'.encode()
b'\xd7\x90\xd7\x91\xd7\x92'
```

but you got its representation instead of the actual string.

```
>>> repr('אבג'.encode())
"b'\\xd7\\x90\\xd7\\x91\\xd7\\x92'"
```

Wrapping your value in quotes creates a string that `literal_eval` can restore to the representation shown above, which can be *further* evaluated to a "real" byte string that can be decoded.